# Parent process automatically killing child_processes in Node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process

It appears that by default when you call process.exit() on a Node.js parent process, it kills the child processes that it spawned. If this is correct, what is the best way to prevent that from happening?

One guess that I had, that didn't work, was to attempt to override the default behavior of SIGTERM, by doing this in the child code:

```
process.on('SIGTERM',function(msg){
    console.log('SIGTERM...');
});
```

but that obviously won't work because it just adds a nominal listener, and doesn't override any behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`options.detached`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached) to `true` to make the child process the leader of a new process group and session.

Example

```
 var child = spawn('prg', [], {
   detached: true,
   stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ]
 });
```

Comment: @AlexMills when I tried a fork it was detached by default meaning the script still executed after process.exit on the main thread

Comment: huh I had the opposite experience, let me double check